# how to correctly write plugins for jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

for me need some tips about **how to correctly write plugins for jquery.**

I began to study this question from the official website JQuery http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

And I decided to write your own sticky header plug-in *(I know that the Internet is full of various examples, I just need tips on writing functions)*

And so. I wrote a simple function that works fine.

```
function stickynav(el) {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
                $(el).css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                $(el).stop().animate({height : '40px',lineHeight : '40px'}, 200);
            } else {
                $(el).css({position: 'static'});
                $(el).stop().animate({height : '80px',lineHeight : '80px'}, 200);
            }

});

stickynav('nav');
```

After I decided to try to write the same function but with the advice of the JQuery team.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.stickynav = function(options){
    settings = $.extend({
      topSpacing: 0,
      initialHeight: '80px',
      resHeight: '40px'
    }, options);

    var $window = $(window)

    var scrolling = function(){
    $window.scroll(function(){
        if( $window.scrollTop() > settings.topSpacing ) {
            $(this).css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            $(this).stop().animate({height : settings.resHeight}, 200);
        } else {
            $(this).css({position: 'static'});
            $(this).stop().animate({height : settings.initialHeight}, 200);
        }
    });
    };
    return this.each(scrolling); 
 };
})(jQuery);

$('nav').stickynav();
```

And the result was a bit confused, I did something wrong.

**Please help and if not it is difficult to explain changes.**

Comment: Is the DOM loaded? (that is, is `$("nav").stickynav()` inside a `.ready` clause?)

Comment: of course:) all inside $(document).ready(function() { .. });

Comment: What was the outcome?

Comment: What does "a bit confused" mean? What did the code do?

Comment: script does not work, nav css not changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem i see is that inside the `$window.scroll` function you use `this`.
But `this` refers to the window in that context..

You will need to store a reference to the `nav` element and use that instead of `this`.

So the whole `var scrolling = ...` should become

```
var scrolling = function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $window.scroll(function(){
        if( $window.scrollTop() > settings.topSpacing ) {
            self.css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            self.animate({height : settings.resHeight}, 200);
        } else {
            self.css({position: 'static'});
            self.animate({height : settings.initialHeight}, 200);
        }
    });
};
```

---

An additional improvement would be to store the current state of the fixed nav, so that you do not do the animation on each scroll but only when you want to change the state..

Demo code at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ALDjx/2/

```
var scrolling = function () {
        var self = $(this);
        self.data('stickyState', false);

        $window.scroll(function () {
            var state = self.data('stickyState'),
                shouldBeFixed = $window.scrollTop() > settings.topSpacing;

            if (!state && shouldBeFixed) {
                self.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px'
                }).animate({
                    height: settings.resHeight
                }, 200);
                self.data('stickyState', true);
            } else if (state && !shouldBeFixed) {
                self.css({
                    position: 'static'
                }).animate({
                    height: settings.initialHeight
                }, 200);
                self.data('stickyState', false);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Can you still say good websites or books where I can better understand the writing jquery functions and plugins?